# What is this whole thing called?

Tags: terminology, circles, graphing-functions, curves, locus

What is the figure in this animation called?

[image: https://i.ibb.co/CKcztht/Locus-Midpoint.gif]

The black dot is mid point of the green line segment joining the purple dot & the green dot. The green dot rotates 5 times as fast as the purple dot. The locus of the black dot is the red curve.

- What is this red curve called?
- Where to learn more about it?
- What are applications of it?
- In which field this is used?

Comment: Looks like four cardioids superimposed.

Comment: Does the picture depend on the initial position of the purple and the green?

Comment: Initial position of purple and green dots determines the length of line segment connecting them & also the position of their mid point (black dot). The Red Curve shifts according to the initial position of purple & green dots but the shape of the Red Curve remains same irrespective of initial position of purple & green dots unless the speed of rotation of green dot is changed with respect to purple dot. In this GIF Ratio =>  Speed of Green Dot : Speed of Purple Dot = 5 : 1

Comment: If the circles are $(a+\cos(t),a+\sin(t))$ and $(-a+\cos(5t),-a+\sin(5t))$ then the midpoint is given by $x=\frac{\cos(5t)+\cos(t)}{2}, y=\frac{\sin(5t)+\sin(t)}{2}$ 
Now use [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) to eliminate `R=QQ[c,s,x,y,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]` `I=ideal(x-(1/2)*(c^5-10*s^2*c^3+5*s^4*c+c),y-(1/2)*(s^5+5*s*c^4-10*s^3*c^2+s),c^2+s^2-1)` `gens gb I` and you have an implicit equation for your curve `16*x^10+80*x^8*y^2+160*x^6*y^4+160*x^4*y^6+80*x^2*y^8+16*y^10-24*x^8-96*x^6*y^2-144*x^4*y^4-96*x^2*y^6-24*y^8+9*x^6+27*x^4*y^2+27*x^2*y^4+9*y^6-x^4+2*x^2*y^2-y^4=0`

Comment: The implicit equation found is correct !!  :-)   .

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be similar to an **epitrochoid**, which is given by

$$
x=m\cos(t)-h\cos(mt/b)\\
y=m\sin(t)-h\sin(mt/b)
$$

where $t\in[0,2\pi]$. In this case, $m=h=10 \text{ and } b=2$. The figure below shows the results for various cases of $m=h \text{ and } b=2$.

Technically, the epitrochoid is the roulette of a point $P$ attached to a circle $S$ rolling about the outside of a fixed circle $C$. See, for example, *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, J. Dennis Lawrence, Dover, 1972.[image: epitrochoid demo]

Comment: Thanks !! Thanks !! Thanks !!